# Creating models from vertex groups

Tags: vertex-groups

I have a humanoid model with its parts like head, torzo, leg etc assigned to vertex groups with corresponding names. I want to make models from these vertex groups. Is there a way to accomplish this without deleting the other vertex groups.

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as selecting the vertices in the vertex group and pressing <kbd>P</kbd> key and selecting *Selection* from the drop down menu.

Comment: If each vertex group is comprised of connected vertices, and those are not connected to any other group(s), you could also use _Separate by loose parts_, to separate all in one go.